# How to properly display "No results found" in php?

Tags: php

In this code I want to display if the results are found or not. The logical error here is that even though the results are now found it will still display the "No results Found".

```
        $search = $_POST['lastname'];

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contact where lastname = '$search'");

        $trap = mysql_query("SELECT lastname FROM contact where lastname = '$search'");

        //for trapping input
        if($trap!=$search){
            echo "No Results Found";
        }
        if($trap==$search){
            echo " ";
        }
        //the logical error is that the "No Results Found" is still displayed even if the results are now found  


        echo"<table border=1>";
        echo"<tr><th>Lastname</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Address</th></tr>";

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {   
            echo "<tr>" . "<td>" .$row['lastname']."</td>" . "<td>" .$row['firstname']. "</td>" . "<td>" .$row['address']. "</td>" . "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I'm not a `php` developer, but could that be that `$search` is a string and `$trap` trap is an array?

Comment: `$search` is a string. `$trap` is a [resource](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php). `$trap!=$search` is true, that's why your code shows "No Results Found". I don't understand the logic of what you are trying to do here. Have a look at [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) maybe?

Comment: In addition to that, [**don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: use `mysql_num_rows()` and JOINS / UNION could also come in handly.

Comment: mysql_num_rows() is a great idea thanks.